# Conditional Rendering of Widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-widget, flutter-layout

Hello I am new to flutter and have created a form builder app. I am using Cloud Firestore as my database. The issue I am having is trying to render specific widgets based on a conditional. I have build the form and have the object data set up like this: Each projects has a list of Questions objects that hold the question information. I want to iterate through the question objects and check the question type then based on that question type render a certain widget (EX. Multiple choice, image upload, short answer, etc). Ideally it would be display as one question per page with a next button. **I would like to stay on one page and just call/display other widgets/functions as the user presses next.**

The issue is that I can not get the widgets to render and/or redirect by a conditional statement. Right now I set up a simple for each loop with a switch statement nested inside however since the iteration continues until it the last object the pages never render. My goal is to add a button when on pressed would continue the iteration.

I have a view project page that sets up the GetProject object and then calls the necessary class functions to get the data from firestore.

```
class Questions{
  final String question;
  final String number;
  final String type;
  Questions({this.question, this.number, this.type});
  List<String> answers = new List();
}

class GetProject {
  final String docID;
  final String title;
  GetProject({this.docID, this.title});

  List<Questions> questions = new List();

   //....Class Functions below not relevant

}
```

Here is what I have so far for the view project page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../models/project.dart';
import '../../Services/getproject.dart';
import 'textquestion.dart';
import 'multiplechoicequestion.dart';
import 'UserLocationInfo.dart';
import 'shortanswerquestion.dart'; 

class ViewProject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String docIDref;
  final String title;
  ViewProject({this.docIDref, this.title});
  @override
  _ViewProjectState createState() => _ViewProjectState();
}

class _ViewProjectState extends State<ViewProject> {


   @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  GetProject project = new GetProject(docID: widget.docIDref, title: widget.title);
  project.getdataFromProject();
  project.questions.forEach((e){
    var type = e.type;
    switch(type){
      case 'TextInputItem':
      return new TextQuestionWidget(question: e);
      case 'MultipleChoice':
      return new MultQuestionWidget(question: e);
      case 'ShortAnswer':
      return new ShortAnswerQuestion(question: e); 
      case 'UserLocation':
      return new UserLocationInfo(question: e); 
    }
    return null; 
  });
  //project.printproj();
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),

      body: Container(
        child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text('Print Values to debug console'),
                    subtitle: Text(''),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                    onTap: () {
                      project.printproj();
                    }
                  ),
            ),

      ),
 );

  }
}
```

Here is an example of what the called widget will look like

```
import '../../Services/getproject.dart';

class UserLocationInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  final Questions question;
  UserLocationInfo({this.question});
  @override
  _UserLocationInfoState createState() => _UserLocationInfoState();
}

class _UserLocationInfoState extends State<UserLocationInfo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very Interesting Question!!

I posted some code using FutureBuilder. When you push the button labeled 'NEXT' a Widget is displayed based in a random number (random number could be a database result)

Thank you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}


class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Future<int> _newRandomNumber() async{
    print("_newRandomNumber");
    return await Random().nextInt(4);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Random Widget")),
          body: Center(child:
          FutureBuilder(
              initialData: 0,
              future:_newRandomNumber(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasData){
                  return getRandomWidget(snapshot.data);
                }
              }
          )
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget getRandomWidget(int randomNumber) {
    switch(randomNumber){
      case 0:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("TextInputItem",textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case 1:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("MultipleChoice",textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case 2:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
          Text("ShortAnswer",textScaleFactor: 4),
          getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
      case 3:
        return Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text("UserLocation",textScaleFactor: 4),
        getNextButton()
        ]);
        break;
    }
  }


  Widget getNextButton(){
      return RaisedButton(
          child: Text("NEXT"),
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _newRandomNumber();
            });

          }
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have never used future builder. This looks promising I will try and implement it and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: This is issue I am having is I set up the project object to contain all of the questions.So I need to call getQuestions before the Future Builder. Then I need to call get type in the future data member of future builder.  The issue is that the project is not initialized before this.

Comment: I dont know if this helps but usually If you need an initial setup, you can use the FutureBuilder parameter constructor 'initialData' or overwrite the method initState.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have few problems that needs to be addressed in your code, so this might not be what exactly you want to achieve, but it will give you a general directions to go from here.

```
class ViewProject extends StatefulWidget {
  final String docIDref;
  final String title;

  ViewProject({this.docIDref, this.title});

  @override
  _ViewProjectState createState() => _ViewProjectState();
}

class _ViewProjectState extends State<ViewProject> {
  GetProject project;
  int _currentPage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // when there is no questions(still loading), show a progress indicator
      body: project.questions == null
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          // IndexedStack will hide all children except the "index"th child
          : IndexedStack(
              index: _currentPage,
              children: project.questions
                  .map((question) => _question(question))
                  .toList(),
            ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    project = GetProject(docID: widget.docIDref, title: widget.title);
    super.initState();
  }

  // Call this function when you want to move to the next page
  void goToNextPage() {
    setState(() {
      _currentPage++;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getQuestions() async {
    // you mentioned you use firebase for database, so 
    // you have to wait for the data to be loaded from the network
    await project.getdataFromProject();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget _question(Questions question) {
    switch (question.type) {
      case 'TextInputItem':
        return TextQuestionWidget(question: e);
      case 'MultipleChoice':
        return MultQuestionWidget(question: e);
      case 'ShortAnswer':
        return ShortAnswerQuestion(question: e);
      case 'UserLocation':
        return UserLocationInfo(question: e);
    }
  }
}
```

I was not sure where you wanted to call the goToNextPage(), so you would have to decide where to call it.

Comment: I do like how this example I am going to try an implement it. Thank you for you response!